# Access 2010 allowing multiple users/ Implementing group security

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, database-security

I'm creating an Access 2010 database and would like some clarification when it comes to concurrency and security. What I would like is upon starting the app only a menu form to be displayed with several buttons including a login button. Most buttons would be disabled until after the user logs in at which point based on their permission group; Viewer(Deafault), Worker, Editor, Admin.

Also, Admin should be the only one to be able to see the access database while the others are restricted to seeing the forms only.

I was just testing the default concurrency implementation but saving my database to a shared network and having myself and a co-worker try to access it. Found out if one accessed the database it locked it from others, and if we both tried at the same time it became read-only.

So I'm just looking for tips on how to start this.

Answer (score 2):

For an Access database all users must have as a minimum read, write and modify permissions on the folder in which the database resides. This is because MS Access creates a lock file and if the second user does not have permissions to modify the lock file, the cannot get access to the database. Delete permissions may also be useful, to remove the lockfile when they are the last person out.

Comment: Hey Remou, tanks for the response but it doesn't really help me. Is there any articles/sites you can recommend for more information.

Comment: I thought your problem was that the Access database became read only. What is the actual problem? If you want serious security, Access is not the right choice.

Comment: No the security is more so protecting users from themselves. I'm looking into workgroups now so I think that's what I'm looking for. But I guess to follow up on your previous answer where would I alter the read/modify permissions? Is it just adjusting the file/folders security themselves or is it something through access?

Comment: These are Windows file and folder permissions I am talking about. It is almost impossible to protect MS Access from a determined clueless user.