# User permissions in Access 2010 and 2013

Tags: ms-access-2010

I saw this post while searching for the same thing - limited access for most users except admins. I very much like the look of the screenshot and result of the mentioned DoCmd.

[User permissions in microsoft access 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386861/user-permissions-in-microsoft-access-2010)

This is exactly the form only view that I am after. How is this implemented so that it runs for most users but not the admin when they open the database? Is there a better way to restrict a user's access? Will it still work when we migrate to 2013?